# Cinder or pure OpenGL for iOS development

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, interface-builder, cinder

As im quite new to obj-C but on the other hand a common user of CPP and ANSI C, im a bit out of my comfortzone working with obj-C.

So people might ask, why i dont learn obj-C? Id love to learn it, but unfortunately im in a very tight schedule due to my uni project i would like to get as much working as possible.

I have worked a little with obj-C and run through tutorials, but i dont see myself being capable of creating big amounts of precious code as i would with CPP.

Yesterday i got familiar with Cinder framework and tried out some examples, which resulted in quite rapid results, especially with OpenGL and math libraries.

What bothers me right now is the capability of working with the XCode interface builder and binding the storyboard or xib files to the project.

Is there a creative way to combine the great GUI with Cinder in XCode, or am i "forced" to go back to pure obj-C and my libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity were you able to go ahead with Cinder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into any of the frameworks built using other languages you may be more comfortable with that are specifically designed for iOS (and Android) game and app development?

ImpactJS - http://impactjs.com/

Corona SDK - http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

The key features with these as well is that you write your code once and it works across multiple platforms, and may be easier and quicker for you if you know JavaScript or Lua (and the learning curve is smaller on these languages typically anyways).

Comment: I have been looking at alot of different frameworks, but often i have found them a bit too heavy and way beyond what i actually needed. My requirements are having full capability of using OpenGL-ES, GUI and I/O (wireless, gyro etc.). The project is for visualisation and real-time control of industrial tool. So basically any game development framework is way out of my scope. I tried Cocos3D and found it extremely heavy for my purpose.